# How to convert fast bigquery RowIterator to arrow or parquet file

Tags: python, flask, google-bigquery, parquet, pyarrow

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq    

query = f"""
    SELECT * FROM `{table_path}.{table_id}`
    """
query_result = b_client.query(query).result()
bq_data_arrow = query_reuslt.to_arrow() # 8 seconds
sink = pa.BufferOutputStream() # parquet File pybytes,
pq.write_table(bq_data_arrow, sink, compression='snappy')
buf = sink.getvalue().to_pybytes()
```

This is my code When I receive request Then return parquet file

First IM using python google cloud bigquery

reuqeust have table id So First query to bigquery table

And then change to arrow and parquet file

But so late!!!!!!

bigquery result RowIterator to_arrow() this code is so long.... like 10seconds

How to more fast speed to return?????

Comment: Could you try some optimization in your select query? For more information, you can refer to these [link1](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs#avoid_select_) and [link2](https://towardsdatascience.com/14-ways-to-optimize-bigquery-sql-for-ferrari-speed-at-honda-cost-632ec705979).