# How to transfer big data? bigquery to Frontend

Tags: google-bigquery, frontend, bigdata, parquet, pyarrow

I have a question for big data transfer

I'm testing my code. But so late....

When receive table id in flask

Use SQL in Bigquery get table data

But table data so big 130000rows and 33 columns

And all data must need

many think, many search after using parquet format

So When receving request return parquet file (bigquery table data)

But so late.... 11seconds

Have some good idea to transfer big data to frontend?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert fast bigquery RowIterator to arrow or parquet file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76338111/how-to-convert-fast-bigquery-rowiterator-to-arrow-or-parquet-file)